# Can not modify Remore Procedure Call (RPC) service

Tags: windows-service, rpc

I have an admin account on my windows, and I used to disable the RPC service before, but recently I can't even modify that. It is permanently disabled, and I can't change its properties. Does anyone have a clue to tell me what could be the reason?

[RPC Service is disabled for editting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A07W.png)

Answer (score 1):

The controls are dimmed due to the RPC Service is a dependency for all other Windows services.  If you want to disable it, change the following registry value from 2 to 4 and restart:

```
Key: HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\RpcSs  
Value: Start
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this but when I want to do this, it prompts, "Can not edit start: error writing the value's new content"

Comment: That is correct. The system is configured to prevent this casual modification. The permissions need to be modified to allow this. One way would be to use SysInternals PsExec: `psexec.exe -s -i cmd.exe`. Run regedit as system in the new cmd window. You can modify the owner of the key and/or change the value. Note: this will cause nearly all services to fail to start, and may prevent the system from starting.